# How can I read a file property that I've created with Appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've followed [Google's documentation for how to add file properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#add_file_properties) with the Advanced Drive Service. I've been pouring over their documentation pages to find out how to read these file properties.

For example:
Here's the example function they gave for adding file permissions:

```js
/**
 * Adds a custom app property to a file. Unlike Apps Script's DocumentProperties,
 * Drive's custom file properties can be accessed outside of Apps Script and
 * by other applications; however, appProperties are only visible to the script.
 * @param {string} fileId The ID of the file to add the app property to.
 */
function addAppProperty(fileId) {
  try {
    let file = {
      'appProperties': {
        'department': 'Sales'
      }
    };
    // Updates a file to add an app property.
    file = Drive.Files.update(file, fileId, null, {
      'fields': 'id,appProperties'
    });
    console.log(
      'ID: %s, appProperties: %s',
      file.id,
      JSON.stringify(file.appProperties, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

Then here's how I plan to use that function and read the permissions:

```js
//GDocFile is a 
addAppProperty(/*fileID*/);
Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById(/*fileID*/).appProperties);
```

Running the second code block results in: `null`

**Can someone explain how to retrieve the permissions correctly? Or better yet, point me to the correct documentation too?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current stage, there are 2 properties at the custom file properties on Drive API. Those are `properties` and `appProperties`. `properties` is the public property. `appProperties` is the private property. In your script, `appProperties` is used. So, when you want to retrieve the values of `appProperties`, it is required to be the same client that `appProperties` is added. Please be careful about this.

If you ran your showing script and `appProperties` is added, please test the following script with the same Google Apps Script project. The sample script for retrieving the values of `appProperties` is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set your file ID.

  const { appProperties } = Drive.Files.get(fileId, { fields: "appProperties" });
  console.log(appProperties);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of `appProperties` are shown in the log.

#### Note:

- In this sample, it supposes that Drive API v3 has already been enabled at Advanced Google services. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Add custom file properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/properties)
- [Method: files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get)

Comment: Wow thanks, quick and succinct answer. This is exactly what I needed. Might I ask where you read about how to use these methods?

Comment: @JJeremy991 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. "Method: files.get" can be seen in [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get). Unfortunately, the Drive API of Advanced Google services is not published officially. But, in this case, when the autocompletion of the script editor is used, you can see how to use it. [My report](https://medium.com/google-cloud/taking-advantage-of-auto-completion-of-script-editor-for-google-apps-script-be088a76cd86) might be useful for understanding it.